# Unable to set mouse cursor JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to figure out nor find the answer anywhere on the web.

I've got a JLayeredPane and when it only has one child Panel I am able to correctly set the cursor using setCursor(). The cursor shows up and everything is fine. But when I add an additional JPanel into the JLayeredPane the cursor no longer shows up

for example this works:

```
m_layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
m_layeredPane.setLayout(new WBLayoutManager());
m_layeredPane.add(m_mediaPanel, new Integer(0));
// m_layeredPane.add(m_whiteboardPanel, new Integer(1));

m_layeredPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // WORKS
```

but this doesn't:

```
m_layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
m_layeredPane.setLayout(new WBLayoutManager());
m_layeredPane.add(m_mediaPanel, new Integer(0));
m_layeredPane.add(m_whiteboardPanel, new Integer(1));

m_layeredPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // FAILS
```

Anyone know how i can get custom cursors working within a JLayeredPane

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at `javax.swing.JLayeredPane` source code, you will see its constructor defined like that:

```
public JLayeredPane() {
    setLayout(null);
}
```

which clearly indicates that it needs to handle components layout by itself.
Hence you can guess (although it is not documented, I would consider it a documentation bug) that you should not change the layout of `JLayeredPane`.

Answer (score 2):

While the topic is old, none of the answers was satisfying. I resolved the problem calling to the setCursor method of the JLayeredPane in this way:

```
this.getParent().setCursor( Cursor.getDefaultCursor() );
```

Where "this" is the component I want to change the cursor to. Its parent is the JLayeredPane (since it is added to it).

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me when using the demo code the the [How to Use Layered Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) tutorial.

Based on the 3 lines of code the only difference I can see from the tutorial is that you are using a layout manager.

Compare your code with the tutorial to find other differences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the first working code, but placing the m_mediaPanel on level 1? This probably won't work either. I think this is due to the fact that the panel that is on top determines the cursor. On level 0 the layered pane itself can determine this.